# Sonata Admin entities translation on Symfony 3

Tags: translation, admin, entities, sonata, symfony-3.3

Did someone succed in translating Sonata Admin entities on Symfony 3 (actually I'm using 3.3).

I tried different solutions, but none really worked.
With gedmo translation, the main problem is that the translations are saved for the differents languages on the database, but then in the admin (list end forms too) the Sonata bundle only dispays the default locale translation, although a different flag/translation is clicked/choosed.

I also tried with KNP tarnslation bundle, and with A2lix translation, but these two have the exat same problem: when you set (in the admin class) a field as "sortable" then in the record list when you try to sort by thet field, Symfony throw an error, because the translation systems try to crete an association with another field tha not exists!

Anyway, staying on the Gedmo soultion, the main problem is that (putting apart the A2lix solution because of the problem I already mentioned) I don't know how set a field as translatable in the admin class (BlogPostAdmin.php) because simply using the config files and the entity and translation class, does not seem to work. The problem, as already said, is that the translations are saved in the database, but are not displayed in the admin lists/forms.

Here are my config and entities files:

AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            /// These are the other bundles the SonataAdminBundle relies on
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Sonata\TranslationBundle\SonataTranslationBundle(),

            // And finally, the storage and SonataAdminBundle
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),

            // stof [used in Sonata translations]
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),

            // assetic
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: it

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
#        mappings:
#            # Doctrine extensions
#            translatable:
#                type: annotation
#                alias: Gedmo
#                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
#                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity/MappedSuperclass"

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]

sonata_translation:
    locales: [it, en]
    default_locale: %locale%
    # here enable the types you need
    gedmo:
         enabled: true
#    knplabs:
#        enabled: true
    #phpcr:
    #    enabled: true

sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout: admin/layout.html.twig

assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

#stof_doctrine_extensions:
#    #default_locale: %locale%
#    orm:
#        default:
#            sluggable: true
#            timestampable: true
```

services.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    locale: 'it'
    locales: ['it', 'en']

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'

    admin.category:
            class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
            arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, ~]
            tags:
                - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
            public: true

    admin.blog_post:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\BlogPostAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Blog post }
        public: true


    # Doctrine Extension listeners to handle behaviors
    gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            #- [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ it ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ false ] ]
            - [ setPersistDefaultLocaleTranslation, [ false ] ]
```

BlogPost.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\AbstractPersonalTranslatable;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\TranslatableInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\AbstractPersonalTranslation;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Traits\Gedmo\PersonalTranslatableTrait;

/**
 * BlogPost
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BlogPostRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="AppBundle\Entity\Translations\BlogPostTr")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */

class BlogPost implements TranslatableInterface
{
    use PersonalTranslatableTrait;

    /**
     * Post locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener's locale
     *
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     */
    protected $locale;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="blogPosts")
     */
    private $category;

    public function setCategory(Category $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="draft", type="boolean")
     */
    private $draft = false;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return BlogPost
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     *
     * @return BlogPost
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    /**
     * Set draft
     *
     * @param boolean $draft
     *
     * @return BlogPost
     */
    public function setDraft($draft)
    {
        $this->draft = $draft;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get draft
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getDraft()
    {
        return $this->draft;
    }

    // TRANSLATION
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Translations\BlogPostTr", mappedBy="object", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $translations;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function getTranslations()
    {
        return $this->translations;
    }

    public function addTranslation(AbstractPersonalTranslation $t)
    {
        $this->translations->add($t);
        $t->setObject($this);
    }

    public function removeTranslation(AbstractPersonalTranslation $t)
    {
        $this->translations->removeElement($t);
    }

    public function setTranslations($translations)
    {
        $this->translations = $translations;
    }

    /**
     * Sets translatable locale
     *
     * @param string $locale
     */
    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
}
```

BlogPostTr.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Translations;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\AbstractPersonalTranslation;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_post_translation",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *         "locale", "object_id", "field"
 *     })}
 * )
 */
class BlogPostTr extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{
    /**
     * Convinient constructor
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function __construct($locale = null, $field = null, $content = null)
    {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($content);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\BlogPost", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $object;
}
```

BlogPostAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class BlogPostAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->tab('Post')
            ->with('Content', array('class' => 'col-md-9'))
            ->add('title', 'text')
//            ->add('title', 'translatable_field', array(
//                'allow_extra_fields' => true,
//                'field' => 'title',
//                'personal_translation' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Translations\BlogPostTr',
//                'property_path' => 'translations',
//            ))
            ->add('body', 'textarea')
            ->end()
            ->end()
            ->tab('Publishing options')
            ->with('Meta data', array('class' => 'col-md-3'))
            ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
                'property' => 'name',
            ))
            ->end()
            ->end();
    }





//    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
//    {
//        $datagridMapper->add('title');
//    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('title');
    }

    public function toString($object)
    {
        return $object instanceof BlogPost
            ? $object->getTitle()
            : 'Blog Post'; // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem. Actually I had two problems:

1. Entities weren't implementing Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\TranslatableInterface. And even if its added later, symfony cache needs to be cleared.
2. I found that during Sonata Admin installation or one of sonata bundles I've added  DoctrineExtensionListener like [shown here](https://gist.github.com/jeroendesloovere/0e339b0c90449e507066d84933411639). Inside that listener Gedmo initiates current locale and of course it doesn't know anything about SonataTranslateBundle.

So I would recommend to dump(debug) symfony locale from request parameters, sonata translation locale and gedmo initiated locale and check that these are synced.

In the end I've setup locale to be [stored in user session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) and updated DoctrineExtensionListener to use locale from session.